# Which programming language (or machine language) first used line numbers?

Tags: history

Fortran II (1958) was **recorded** using line numbers, from what I can tell.  For example, the first five columns of this IBM punch card are titled "statement number".

[image: Punch card from a typical Fortran program by Arnold Reinhold]
*Punch card from a typical Fortran program.* Arnold Reinhold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FortranCardPROJ039.agr.jpg)

> Columns 1 to 5 may be used to write numbers by which the statement may subsequently be referenced.
>   ([Fortran II General Information Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/fortran/F28-8074-3_FORTRANII_GenInf.pdf). 1963. p. 7)

Was Fortran 2 the first programming language (or machine language) **to be recorded** using line numbers?

Line numbers are not a requirement for a programming language (or machine language), but they are of such practical importance that I am curious if there ever was a language **recorded** without them.

Obviously, if a program is read into addressable memory, each instruction has a memory address. This question is **not** about memory addresses, it is about the **recorded** form of the program, on the media on which the program is recorded **at rest**, e.g. a punch card.

Comment: The numbers in columns 1..5 are not _line_ numbers, but _labels_, which in Fortran must be numerical. The numbers used for labels were pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: Columns 1..5 were for statement labels, which had to be numbers.  Columns 73..80 were for card sequence numbers.  If you were unfortunate enough to drop your card deck, having sequence numbers on all of the cards meant that you could run your deck through a card sorter and get it back into the correct order.

Comment: The first DoS in computer history was to insert a punchcard into another student's deck containing `666  goto 666`. Ok, the first one I got aware of.

Answer (score 9):

You are not going to find an antecedent to the [first published computer program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace#/media/File:Diagram_for_the_computation_of_Bernoulli_numbers.jpg), written by Ada Lovelace for Babbage's difference engine, published in 1841.

Note that leftmost column, "Number of Operation".

I think that beats the other answers by a full century though perhaps it loses points for never having actually been run.

Answer (score 3):

Probably Dartmouth BASIC (Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code), in 1964.  In the original language, every line was required to have a line number, you could only put one statement on a line, and lines were "interpreted" (in a general sense: Dartmouth BASIC, while having a nice interactive user environment, was in fact compiler-based) in ascending order by line number.

Comment: Dartmouth BASIC, 1964, had numbered statements. Every statement had a number, in ascending order, but they did not have to be consecutive. Typical programs would initially use an increment of 10, leaving room for new statements between them. The numbers were used as labels for gotos, etc., and also were used for editing: to replace a statement, you simply typed in a replacement statement with the same number, and to delete one you typed the number with no text following.

Answer (score 2):

The [PAF](http://www.feb-patrimoine.com/english/paf_starynkevitcha.htm) compiler on [CAB500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAB500) (written by my late father Dimitri Starynkevitch in 1958-1960; see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268760973_Calcul_des_formules_dans_le_systme_P._A._F._%28Programmation_automatique_des_formules_sur_CAB_500%29) in Chiffres 1961) generated a line number for every line of code interactively typed (while a teenager, I played on a CAB500 in the Palais de la Découverte museum in Paris, near 1975?)

CAB500 was a drum based machine built in France. AFAIK, it was only sold in Europe (and mostly in France).

<sup>(so I am one of the few persons in the world involved in compilers -thru my [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) tool- whose father also wrote compilers.)</sup>

Comment: Wah!! Extremely impressive, Basile. You very very fortunate to have such a father.

Answer (score 2):

My first computer was an IBM 1620 that used punched cards.  It was produced in the late 1950's.  When writing assembler (SPS) the first five columns of the card were for line number.

There was a practical use for those. If / when you dropped the cards you could take them to the sorter.  Been there, done that.